# What is the quickest way to find the sum of $x$ and $y$ in this system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

$$
\begin{align*}
2\left( x-\frac{1}{3}\right) -\frac{3}{2}\left( y-\frac{1}{6}\right)&=0 \tag 1\\ 
3\left( y-\frac{1}{2}\right) +\frac{8}{3}\left( x-\frac{1}{6}\right)&=0 \tag 2\\  
\end{align*}
$$
Consider the system of equations above. If $(x,y)$ is the solution to the system, then what is the value of the sum of $x$ and $y$?

I've used the solving for $x$, and then, finding $y$ method, but I feel, that there must be a faster way to find $x+y$. 
 Does anyone know any tricks?

Comment: Solving the system consists in reducing its matrix to a triangular one and performing back substitution. However, you can aim instead to getting a row $[1,1]$ in the matrix by doing row transformations. If you do that the right hand side is the value of $x+y$

Comment: Another way can be to put $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$ and $y=\frac{a-b}{2}$ and solve only for $a$.

Answer (score 2):

In general, we must multiply $(1)$ by $a$ and $(2)$ by $b$ so that when the two equations are added we get the coefficients of $x$ and $y$ the same:
$$2a+\frac{8}{3}b=3b-\frac{3}{2}a \Rightarrow 21a=2b \Rightarrow a=2, b=21.$$

Hence:
$$60(x+y)=(\frac23-\frac14)\cdot2+(\frac32+\frac49)\cdot21 \Rightarrow x+y=\frac{25}{36}.$$

Comment: +1, as far as I can se this is the only method that does not calculte x and y before x+y and seems to be shorter than other methods to calculate x+y, but this is hard to judge. Nevertheless the savings are so small that I think one should calculate x and y with the standard methods and then calculate x+y.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
2\left( x-\frac{1}{3}\right) -\frac{3}{2}\left( y-\frac{1}{6}\right)&=0 \\ 
3\left( y-\frac{1}{2}\right) +\frac{8}{3}\left( x-\frac{1}{6}\right)&=0 \\  
\end{align*}$$
Multiply the first by $2$ and the second by $21$
$$\begin{align*}
4 x-3 y&=\frac{5}{6} \\ 
56 x+63 y&= \frac{245}{6}\\  
\end{align*}$$
Then add the two equations
$$60x+60y= \frac{250}{6}\rightarrow x+y=\frac{25}{36}$$

Answer (score 0):

Begin with the system of two equations: 
$$
\begin{align*}
2\left( x-\frac{1}{3}\right) -\frac{3}{2}\left( y-\frac{1}{6}\right)&=0, \\ 
3\left( y-\frac{1}{2}\right) +\frac{8}{3}\left( x-\frac{1}{6}\right)&=0. \\  
\end{align*}
$$
Multiply through the first equation by $\color{blue}{12}$ and multiply through the second equation by $\color{green}{18}$ so that we can clear the denominator for both equations: 
$$
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{4}\cdot 2\left( \color{blue}{3}\left( x-\frac{1}{3}\right)\right) 
- \color{blue}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{2}\left(\color{blue}{6}\left( 
 y-\frac{1}{6}\right) \right)&=0, \\ 
\color{green}{9}\cdot 3\left( \color{green}{2}\left( y-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) +\color{green}{3}\cdot \frac{8}{3}\left( 
\color{green}{6}\left(x-\frac{1}{6}\right) \right)&=0. \\  
\end{align*}
$$
Now, multiply out the numbers in blue and in green: 
$$
\begin{align*}
8\left(  3 x-1  \right) 
- 3 \left(6y-1\right)&=0, \\ 
 27 \left( 2y-1 \right) + 8 
\left( 6x-1 
  \right)&=0. \\  
\end{align*}
$$
Expand: 
$$
\begin{align*}
24x -8 -18y+3  &= 0, \\ 
54 y - 27 + 48x-8 &= 0. \\  
\end{align*}
$$
Simplify further as: 
$$
\begin{align*}
24x - 18y  &= 8-3=5, \\ 
48x + 54 y  &= 27+8=35. \\  
\end{align*}
$$
Write the two equations in matrix form: 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
24 & -18 \\ 
48 & 54 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ 
y \\ 
\end{pmatrix} 
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
5 \\ 
35 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}. 
$$
Write this as an augmented matrix: 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
24 & -18 & 5\\ 
48 & 54 & 35 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}  
$$ 
and then row-reduce (multiply the first row by $-2$ and then add the corresponding numbers to the second row): 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
24 & -18 & 5\\ 
0 & 90 & 25 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}.   
$$ 
Divide the second row by $5$ to get: 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
24 & -18 & 5\\ 
0 & 18 & 5 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}.   
$$
Add the second row to the first row: 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
24 & 0 & 10\\ 
0 & 18 & 5 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}.   
$$
Divide the first row by $24$ and divide the second row by $18$: 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \frac{5}{12}\\ 
0 & 1 & \frac{5}{18} \\ 
\end{pmatrix}.   
$$
So 
$$
x= \frac{5}{12} \mbox{ and } y= \frac{5}{18}, 
$$
and we conclude 
$$
\boxed{x+y =  \frac{5}{12} +  \frac{5}{18} = \frac{25}{36}}.   
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  let $s=x+y\,$, then substituting $x=s-y$ back into the equations gives:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
2\left((s-y)-\frac{1}{3} \right) - \frac{3}{2}\left(y-\frac{1}{6}\right) &= 0 \quad\iff\quad 2s - \frac{7}{2}y = \frac{5}{12}\\
\frac{8}{3}\left((s-y)-\frac{1}{6}\right) + 3\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right) &= 0 \quad\iff\quad \frac{8}{3}s + \frac{1}{3}y=\frac{35}{18}
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Eliminate $y$ between the latter equations (for example multiply the first one by $1/3\,$, the second one by $7/2$ and add up), then solve the resulting equation for $s=x+y$.

Comment: Nice! It is faster to eliminate the $y$ and thus solve for $s$ using the last two equations.